# Getting this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 487 out of bounds for length 487

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to print out the drop down list using below program but it is throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`,

however it is printing around 70-80 list and after that it throws an error. how can i print all the values in the console.

```
public void searchText() {
        searchTxtField.sendKeys("m31");
        ArrayList <WebElement> list = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3BEcOp']//div"));
        System.out.println(list.size());

        for(int i=0 ; i<=list.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
```

and below is the error I am getting.

```
FAILED: verifySearchFunctionality
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 487 out of bounds for length 487
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:426)
    at com.flipkart.qa.pages.SearchPageFK.searchText(SearchPageFK.java:34)
    at com.flipkart.qa.testcases.SearchPageFKTest.verifySearchFunctionality(SearchPageFKTest.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Should be `i < list.size()` instead of `i <= list.size()`.

Comment: Use list.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.getText())); instead of for loop.

Comment: Note that index ranges from `0` to `size - 1`. Replace `i<=list.size()` with `i<list.size()`.

Comment: i<list.size() worked for me..but may I know the exact reason why it is so and giving error with i<=list.size()

Comment: @vishalgupta It's because you are trying to fetch the data of index which is not present in the list container. As index starts from 0 to list.size()-1. And you are trying to fetch list.size() which is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate till the `(length of List) - 1`

Removing  `=` from `i <= list.size()` condition should solve your problem

```
for(int i=0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void searchText() {
    searchTxtField.sendKeys("m31");
    ArrayList <WebElement> list = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3BEcOp']//div"));
    System.out.println(list.size());

    list.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.getText()));
}
```

Use above mentioned code. This will solve the IndexOutOfBoundsException exception in any case. Just check given list is not null else use forEach in every code